# List comprehension with any

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that following is list comprehension syntax:

```
List2 = [item for item in List1 if item=='test']
```

However for nested list comprehension, the syntax changes to how it would have appeared in a normal program:

```
List3 = [ y for x in toplevelForLoop for y in x ]
```

The if loop can appear after the first or 2nd for loop as per logic but the sequence is like how it would be in a normal program.

Is below acceptable? I am trying to check if item in ListB is contained within item in ListA

Code:

```
for itemA in ListA:

    if any([ itemB in itemA for itemB in ListB ])
```

Is the above code equivalent to the below?

Code:

```
if any([ itemB in itemA for itemA in ListA for itemB in ListB ])
```

Comment: As an aside avoid using a list comprehension with `any` as it prevents short circuiting behaviour. Just remove the `[]` to use a generator and it will stop the first time a true value is encountered.

Comment: Please use nicer variable names. I had almost the whole answer written out, then figured out I misread what you wrote. :P Why not `any(alien in apparent_humans for alien_landing_party in alien_invasion_fleet for alien in alien_landing_party)`? (That's actually not equivalent to what you wrote, but I have no clue what you intended to write, so...)

Comment: Is the above same as- for alient_landing_party in alient_invasion_fleet: any( alien in apparent_humans for alien in alient_landing_party )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehension with multiple `for`s is equivalent to nested `for` loops. These two are equivalent:

```py
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

## With comprehension
b = [
    number
    for numbers in a
    for number in numbers
]

## Without comprehension
b = []
for numbers in a:
    for number in numbers:
        b.append(number)

# b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`any` will be true if any item in the iterator (doesn't need to be a list) is truthy

```py
assert any([True, False, False]) == True
assert any(['string', '', '']) == True
assert any([1, 0, 0]) == True
assert any([False, False, False]) == False
assert any(['', '', '']) == False
assert any([0, 0, 0]) == False
```

---

Your two scenarios are not equivalent. Expanding them a little:

```py
for itemA in ListA:
    if any([ itemB in itemA for itemB in ListB ]):
        print("at least some item from ListB exist in itemA")
```

This code above would print one line for every item from `ListA` that contains any element from `ListB`.

This code below will print only one line if the code above would print at least one line:

```py
if any([ itemB in itemA for itemA in ListA for itemB in ListB ]):
    print("at least some item from ListB exist in at at least one item from ListA")
```

Comment: In code from my question, are the last 2 code concepts equilavant?

Comment: Yes but instead of print if it were a List.append, then eventually both codes would fill the same list items isnt it?

Comment: How would it be a list? If you ware appending to a list, the first one would append as many items as it would print lines. The second would append at most one line

Comment: I mean if we create a List test_list before the program and then instead of print you write test_list.append(itemB)

Comment: itemB is not defined in any of those `if` blocks, it is only defined inside the list comprehension. In the first case you have the value of `itemA`, `ListA` and `ListB` inside the block. In the second one, you have only `ListA` and `ListB`.